# Extracting specific folders in multiple tar.gz files recursively

Tags: linux, bash, tar.gz

I am working with the open Synthetic patient and population health data, [Synthea](https://synthea.mitre.org/downloads).

The dataset comes in a 21gb tar.gz that extracts into a set of tar.gz files that represent the data in a number of data formats.

The extracted source folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- output_11_20170528T113605.tar.gz
|-- output_1_20170524T232103.tar.gz
|-- output_12_20170528T195303.tar.gz
|-- output_2_20170525T073836.tar.gz
|-- output_3_20170525T161555.tar.gz
|-- output_4_20170526T004637.tar.gz
|-- output_5_20170526T091439.tar.gz
|-- output_6_20170526T173337.tar.gz
|-- output_7_20170527T015508.tar.gz
|-- output_8_20170527T102552.tar.gz
|-- output_9_20170527T185007.tar.gz
```

I have tried to extract only the CSV files using the below command, which works well for a single file:

```
tar -zxvf output_1_20170525T073836.tar.gz "output_1*csv*" -C ../synthea_output_folder
```

It would be neat to build a shell script that can iterate over these files and extract the CSV folders from each tar.gz files so that they appear in the synthea_output_folder like so:

```
|-- output_11/csv
|-- output_1/csv
|-- output_12/csv
|-- output_2/csv
|-- output_3/csv
|-- output_4/csv
|-- output_5/csv
|-- output_6/csv
|-- output_7/csv
|-- output_8/csv
|-- output_9/csv
```

I found a shell script to untar recursively but I don't know how to filter out only the CSV folder from each file:

```
for f in *.tar.gz; do tar -xzvf "$f"; done
```

Comment: What is the intent of "output_1*csv*" ?

Comment: Each tar.gz file, for instance, output_11_20170528T113605.tar.gz, contains a number of data folders based on file format. The only folder in each tar.gz file that I want to extract is the csv folder. I got the syntax from this forum thread: https://superuser.com/questions/746750/extract-specific-folder-from-a-tar-gz

Comment: To clarify, when you untar output_11_20170528T113605.tar.gz, the extracted folder is called output_11.

Comment: How is the "csv folder" determined in the tar.gz file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution**

After tinkering around with the above shell code I managed to extract only the csv folders by adding the *csv* wildcard command:

```
for f in *.tar.gz; do tar -xzvf "$f" "*csv*" -C ../synthea_output; done
```

The output now looks like this:

```
|-- output_1
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_10
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_11
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_12
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_2
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_3
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_4
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_5
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_6
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_7
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
|-- output_8
|   `-- csv
|       |-- allergies.csv
|       |-- careplans.csv
|       |-- conditions.csv
|       |-- encounters.csv
|       |-- immunizations.csv
|       |-- medications.csv
|       |-- observations.csv
|       |-- patients.csv
|       `-- procedures.csv
`-- output_9
    `-- csv
        |-- allergies.csv
        |-- careplans.csv
        |-- conditions.csv
        |-- encounters.csv
        |-- immunizations.csv
        |-- medications.csv
        |-- observations.csv
        |-- patients.csv
        `-- procedures.csv
```